# How to use styled map in TMapView

Tags: android, delphi, maps, firemonkey

I use RAD Studio 10.4.1 and have a TMapView component on my Android app.

No problem with the TMapView, it works well.
On Google Plateform I see that we can styling maps https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling

Thats what I do, I add a plan and a styled map in my Google Cloud Plateform.

To use it on web page we need to do this call :

```
<script 
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/jskey=API_KEY&map_ids=MAP_ID&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

On my app, I have the API_KEY on "Version information" :

```
apiKey=MY_MAPS_API_KEY
```

I try to add the MAP_ID in the manifest but he don't care :

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.MAP_ID" android:value="xxxxx" />
```

How can I use the TMapView with my Map ID ?